# how to add custom field in jTable ASP.Net MVC

Tags: jquery-jtable

I would like to know how to add a custom field column in jTable ASP.net MVC. I will be adding an image icon that will have a link popup to my custom page.

### Solved My Problem:

```
$('#Container').jtable({
    ...
    actions: {
        ...
    },
    fields: {
        TestField: {
            title: ' ',
            sorting: false,
            display: function (data) {
                return "<a href=\"javascript:open_window('Details'," + data.record.ID + ")\">Open details</a>";
            }
        },
    }
});
```